# The issue(ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) related to the mcamara/laravel-localization package

Tags: laravel-localization

I use `mcamara/laravel-localization` package to add a locale segment to all URLs.
I added a route group in the web.php:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [
            'localize', // \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes
            'localeSessionRedirect', // \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect
            'localizationRedirect', // \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter
            'localeViewPath', // \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath
        ],
    ], function () {
      Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
      Route::get('currencies', 'currencies')->name('currencies');
      /* Other routes ... */
});
```

- When accessing the home page `konoha.com/fr`, it works correctly (status code 200)
- On the home page, I fetch(`konoha.com/fr/currencies`) in a JS file, the flow happened:

  - `konoha.com/fr/currencies` (302 Found (from disk cache), Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade)
  - `konoha.com/fr/currencies` (301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache), Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade)
  - (failed)net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
- Commented the line "#add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";" in include.headers
- Also added these middleware (localize, localeSessionRedirect, localizationRedirect, localeViewPath) in the middleware 'web' in RouteServiceProvidor.
  But still got the same issue.
  So, please help to check this issue.
  Thanks!